# Image Processing: Using AdjacentBorders with SelectComponents

Tags: image-processing

I've been doing some image processing and have been having trouble with the `AdjacentBorder` command. I've got an image in which I have several elements that are on the borders, and I was able to use `ComponentMeasurements[image,"AdjacentBorders"]` to obtain the list of what borders these elements touch. However, when I go to use `SelectComponents`, I'm unable to select the elements that are just on one border.

Is this possible, or can I only select the components that are bordering a certain amount of borders?

This is the image I started with this image

[image]

and the code I've used since.

```
j := Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpszz.png"
k := Binarize[j, FindThreshold[j]]
l := SelectComponents[k, "FilledCircularity", -7]
m := ImageCrop[l]
ComponentMeasurements[m, "AdjacentBorders"]
```

> ```
> {1 -> {Top}, 2 -> {Right}, 3 -> {Left}, 4 -> {Left}, 5 -> {Right},
>  6 -> {Bottom, Right}, 7 -> {Left, Bottom}}
> ```

I used `ComponentMeasurements` to ensure that I did have points on the borders, which I did.

Comment: What exactly would be your desired output?

Comment: @Öskå I would like to set up my code so that I could select only the components on one side of the image. I would think that I could use the SelectComponents command for this, but wasn't able to figure out if I was getting the syntax wrong or if those two commands would not work together.

Comment: By "select" you mean highlight on the image?

Comment: Ideally, I'd love to have something similar to the SelectComponents output, where the output would be the same image with just the selected components. However, if they were highlighted on the image, that would also work.

Comment: That would work perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You can use for example `ImageSubtract` as follow:

```
j = Import@"http://i.imgur.com/AC0bvkG.png";
k = Binarize[j, FindThreshold[j]];
l = SelectComponents[k, "FilledCircularity", -7];
m = ImageCrop[l];
comp = ComponentMeasurements[m, {"AdjacentBorders", "BoundingBox"}] /. 
       {{_, Right} | {Right, _} -> {Right}, {_, Left} | {Left, _} -> {Left}};
imgdim = ImageDimensions@m;
Manipulate[
 ImageSubtract[Show[m, ImageSize -> 300], 
  Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[Sequence @@ #] & /@ Cases[comp, Rule[x_, {{i}, y_}] :> y]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, First@imgdim + 1}, {-1, Last@imgdim}}, 
   ImageSize -> 300]], {i, {Top, Left, Right}}]
```

[image]

Or `ImageMultiply` to highlight the different parts:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But there are unfortunately some unselected pixels.

Answer (score 2):

With `SelectComponents` you can do it like this:

```
selectBorder[border_] := SelectComponents[
  m,
  "AdjacentBorders",
  MemberQ[#, border] &
  ]
```

So that `selectBorder /@ {Left, Right, Top, Bottom}` gives

[image: selectBorder example]

But there's a problem, as you can see. `AdjacentBorder` doesn't count elements that don't touch their borders. So a harder question is not how you can use `AdjacentBorder` with `SelectComponents` but how you can find out what the adjacent border of a component is even if it's not touching it. For this particular example I would recommend cropping the image just a bit more so that all elements touch their respective borders.

Comment: Oy oy. Now I feel dumb :)

Comment: @Öskå It takes more brains to write the code in your answer, but yeah, this is simpler :)

Comment: The simpler it is, the smarter ;) :)